# PHP, Mysql chat application. I have no idea

Tags: php, mysql, message

I have 2 kind of profil: boss and user. I want to create an application where users can send messages to the boss profils. Not to the all boss profil just to one of them. And I do not know how can I do it with Mysql tables. Can somebody give me a hint about it? I don't want to write a live chat just a message sender/receiver like -I don't know- gmail.

Thanks for all!

Comment: This is too broad for SO. You will need to create a form, DB connection and writing script, and a reading script for the boss. You also will need to set up some relation between user and boss if they should only be able to communicate with the 1 boss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at [this website ?](http://www.webestools.com/scripts_tutorials-code-source-15-personal-message-system-in-php-mysql-pm-system-private-message-discussion.html)
It's a tutorial on how to make a private messaging system. It seems to be what you want